# Strange hidden layers in PNG image, need to be removed

Tags: python, imagemagick, masking

I have to create a binary mask from an image (a car in a white background)
But the resulting mask seems to be wrong due to the presense of some hidden layers in the original image which cannot be visually seen on the original image.
Originally the image was JPG but I converted it to PNG.

Attached are the original image and resulting binary mask.

[Original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8utS.png)

[Resulting mask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nek4t.png)

Does anyone know what can be the reason and how to fight it?

I think sometime ago I encountered similar problem and solved it with:

```
convert -flatten image.png image.png
```

But this time it doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

As Xenoid has just said, you are starting with an image that does not have a clean white background. So in ImageMagick try this:

```
convert S8utS.png -fuzz 2% -fill white -opaque white -fill black +opaque white -morphology open octagon:5 result.png
```

[image]

The -morphology closes some white holes inside the black area.

Answer (score 0):

No hidden layers... Just plain JPEG compression artifacts that make your white not completely white. If your mask is only where the pixels are exactly (255,255,255) then these pixels are not included. If you cannot obtain th emast using a threshold, then you should increase contrast and/or luminosity to make your not-completely-white real white. This can be done on a copy of the initial image (in other words, you can get the mask from a copy optimized to extract the mask).